# SpringBoot + junit5 + mockito + cxf Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a proxy instance

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, cxf, junit5

My configuration excerpt

```
<...>
    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        SpringBus springBus = new SpringBus();
        LoggingInInterceptor ipt = new LoggingInInterceptor();
        LoggingOutInterceptor opt = new LoggingOutInterceptor();
        ipt.setPrettyLogging(true);
        opt.setPrettyLogging(true);
        springBus.getInInterceptors().add(ipt);
        springBus.getOutInterceptors().add(opt);
        return springBus;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyService getMyServiceProxy() {
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsProxyFactoryBean =
                new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setAddress(MyServiceAddress + ":" +
                MyServicePort + MyServiceAddressPath);
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setServiceClass(MyService.class);
        jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setBus(springBus());
        return jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(MyService.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Client myServiceClentProxy() {
        return ClientProxy.getClient(getMyServiceProxy());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPConduit myServiceAgentConduit() {
        HTTPConduit httpConduit =
                (HTTPConduit) myServiceClentProxy().getConduit();
        httpConduit.setAuthorization(basicAuthorization());
        return httpConduit;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationPolicy basicAuthorization() {
        AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy =
                new AuthorizationPolicy();
        authorizationPolicy.setUserName(myServiceUser);
        authorizationPolicy.setPassword(myServicePassword);
        authorizationPolicy.setAuthorizationType("Basic");

        return authorizationPolicy;
    }
<...>
```

when I try to run my app normally everything just works, but when I try to run a test it throws an
error failing on a phase where configuration is happening.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a proxy instance
```

full error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceClientProxy' defined in class path resource [MyServiceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client]: Factory method 'myServiceClientProxy' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a proxy instance
```

How to solve this issue? What I'm missing do I need any other library besides mockito and Junit?

**Update No. 1**

test case is not even related to cxf itself

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyServiceController.class})
@SpringBootTest
@Import(MyServiceApplication.class)
public class ControllerTest {
@Autowired
private MyServiceController myServiceController;

@MockBean
private MyService myService;

@Test
public void doTest() {
    when(myService.doAction(any(String.class))).thenReturn("empty");
   }
}
```

**Update No.2 regarding the class level annotations**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyServiceController.class})
@SpringBootTest
@Import(MyServiceApplication.class)
```

If I remove any of these annotations, I receive a message

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name myService
```

**Update no.3**
If I remove @MockBean annotation and qualify

```
@Bean(name = "serviceProxy")
public RepositoryWS getMyServiceProxy() {}
```

and

```
@Bean(name = "clientProxy")
public Client myServiceClientProxy() {
    return ClientProxy.getClient(getMyServiceProxy());
}
```

and

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyServiceController.class})
@SpringBootTest
@Import(MyServiceApplication.class)
public class ControllerTest {
@Autowired
private MyServiceController myServiceController;

@MockBean
private MyService myService;

@Test
public void doTest() {
    <deleteThisLine>when(myService.doAction(any(String.class))).thenReturn("empty");</deleteThisLine>
   }
}
```

and if I use @Autowired instead of @MockBean, then again everything works.
I'm confused on why mocking is not working.

**Update no.4**

it seems that error happens here:

> package: java.lang.reflect;

> class: Proxy.class

```
    /*
     * Verify that the object is actually a proxy instance.
     */
    if (!isProxyClass(proxy.getClass())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not a proxy instance");
    }
```

Comment: When/where do you get this error? You only mention a test? Please add your test.

Comment: This won't even compile, nor does the whole test with the load of annotations make anysense. What do you want to accomplish with this test?

Comment: Sorry for inconveniences I updated my post

Comment: As stated the test doesn't make anysense, there are too many annotations interfering with each other. Dit all of them and only leave `@SpringBootTest` or ditch that as well an use `@WebMvcTest(MyServiceCOntroller.class)`.

Comment: When I do as you say it fails to autowire controller class and myService class

Comment: You shouldn't remove the `@Autowired` and `@MockBean`, only the class level annotations.

Comment: Issue is related to myServiceClentProxy method which creates bean, but it does
not work while performing tests

Comment: If you, as stated, only use `@WebMvcTest(MyServiceController.class)` that config class won't even be called.

Comment: I don't see that which is the whole issue. As I repeatedly mention your whole test doesn't make sense, there are too many annotations which interfere with each other. As stated twice before ditch all class annotations and replpace those with `@WebMvcTest(MyServiceController.class)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M. Deinum was right to much cluter was on my ControllerTest class, removing all
annotations, but **@SpringBootTest**, also I had to create configuration solely for
test case

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyServiceApplicationTest.class})
public class ControllerTest {
@Autowired
private MyServiceController myServiceController;

@MockBean
private MyService myService;

@Test
public void doTest() {
    when(myService.doAction(any(String.class))).thenReturn("empty");
   }
}
```